# Need help updating an old Mathematica worksheet

Tags: programming, compatibility

I found a notebook that symbolically applies the multiple time scales method to any differential equations. I don't like just using other people's code so I am going through the author's work line by line. I am new to Mathematica so I am looking up each function and reading about the syntax as I go through the code. Unfortunately I am running into issues because it appears the Mathematica language has changed since the creation of the notebook.

I think I was able to fix the first error I received by removing the  `<<Algebra ReIm;` line since it seems ReIm is an outdated package. The second error I am receiving is

```
Function::flpar: "Parameter specification {T[0],T[1]} in 
Function[{T[0],T[1]},Cos[ω\ T[0]]\ C[1][T[1]]+Sin[ω\ T[0]]\ 
C[2][T[1]]] should be a symbol or a list of symbols."
```

Which I get from line

```
zerosol = DSolve[zeroordereqn == 0, 
   x[0], {T[0], T[1]}] /. {C[_][#2]*Cos[omega_.*#1] + C[_][#2]*Sin[omega_.*#1] -> 
    A[#2]*Exp[I*omega*#1] + Conjugate[A[#2]]*Exp[-I*omega*#1]}
```

I am not sure how to fix this error, I believe it has to do with T[ 0 ] and T[ 1 ] not being initialize properly. I would appreciate any help with the issue.

I have included a [link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2380/) to the notebook file in case you need more information to help answer this question.

I am sorry if this is a simple question, but I am pretty new to Mathematica and not sure where to look to find the solution.

Thanks in advance,

Casey

Answer (score 1):

The error itself may be isolated to this operation:

```
zeroordereqn = ω^2 x[0][T[0],T[1]]+(x[0]^(2,0))[T[0],T[1]];

DSolve[zeroordereqn == 0, x[0], {T[0], T[1]}]
```

`DSolve` gives a result in terms of a `Function` using the parameters `T[0]` and `T[1]` but this is not valid.  Perhaps at some time `DSolve` gave different output but I cannot test that.  However if one replaces `T[0]` and `T[1]` with `t0` and `t1` the error is avoided:

```
DSolve[zeroordereqn == 0 /. {T[0] -> t0, T[1] -> t1}, x[0], {t0, t1}]
```

> ```
> {{x[0] -> Function[{t0,t1},Cos[t0 ω] C[1][t1]+Sin[t0 ω] C[2][t1]]}}
> ```

The fancy replacement at follows the `DSolve` however has no effect which leads me to believe that the output format is no longer compatible with this Notebook.

Comment: @Casey: I agree, but would start from the beginning, which is fixing `InPowers` using `Symbol` instead of indexed variables for `T` and `x` and working down. Therefore, it would be most useful to keep the unmodified workbook open and start out new by copy-pasting and using up-to-date *Mathematica* methods as you go.

Comment: @Jinxed Do you understand the transformation that was intended by the replacement following `DSolve`?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that it is converting the pure function generated by the old *Mathematica* from trigonometrical to exponential form.

Comment: I think I will have a go on this old notebook this afternoon and try to bring it up-to-date from top to bottom. Let's see, if I manage to and how long it might take.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to update the workbook for Mathematica-10-compatibility, but stopped just before the section **Duffing Equation**.

I also did not copy the original explanatory texts (yet), since this will need some refurbishing also.

Here is what I managed so far (just copy, paste and execute):

```
NotebookPut@Uncompress@"1:eJztPQ10HMV5si1kGwcMOAHS8OjZBNtyT7LuJGNLxQJbP0 
aAf6pTDI1/5JW0J699d3va27Nlg1M/AiXQl1Ly05emvJbETUvySFKISYEQUvLchLT0kbbEcc 
FxeHnE/BRcp4G8QF9L7pvdvZvZ2d2Z2dk7nYj8nnd0u7Mz833z/c83s4tH9MF0U0NDQ2Fe6b 
JJN9URXd+bvhzuNJYuN2oFMz3L+dWjZjLp2fDrPPvXBkMv5nsVU7Ful1+ZQ7yCGphbuqzXJ1 
FldAO6HdT3l+6lzyFenu2MJ2UeyKil5yloTp3IpaDeQC5f9KoDbcaYNdYKteEeZyONF+zp/G 
AoBFubzf8Ujdsa/TLsug1drac7IsDd7wXWgDuxIOSRALHRM4cAER5s72pr7+lEY9mJrkneuc 
IwRGLFghyuLdbfDNoMHiQ8TaDrSnS9ym7fGXz/KrsTQeglgLMQ1S45/XBnLZt32io13HVhsI 
PFjFpY2GBJhZ7dSm5cHdKyakGFGgAwlCd+dv62lYv+a90FpxM7obx0z5IRKB99/aExKFdMzN 
WgfOTmNzJQisqaYMQKzLYF1/mAg2JeNQqjhpY3ARMuUk36EBb/HLbwCMwFpUu/oYyamp5z5i 
PBQYU0ABIjbbcEBUPUzfFBnNXy+9Awk23tSevqop8LS39sLGZMLaPl1P5iDgGMHm/Sc6rHuC 
yw+zvaEzaNwo3NRZOfNGfZpHnk+Ct7gOSeOvE2Ij305ua8mquCigwm02DlQAolIAx1Mq/kxt 
QxUKJIDQoqI5IC4EEfatFCN4dUXM6o42h4AGxlq7B2QJTjIZTsuV+VdFPRucAtes7sV7Ja5k 
AKMN+jFw1NNUIBEzwfwUJFBPNu3mvDeG8bQt4VCewWzYjeSrUsEaIcW0JqbGIjd8yB6KFIBk 
OxFF2bMb1n/cZe4iAoGmHW9fcdAm5f185oBsi+JEzNEhMVeFgctTy021AVPyYmqwOAfRNFJc 
MDFEdbQ8pIRo2gLZBuPbqaTmujmpozfVo8h3rHLRHjbpKKo6uGzUacYyZvYXRdaTOOMXAcI7 
VDeI8Uk1N2PFN5Of/jxUc+AUrr6l89eReUX7/juc9B+emmh/5C2o7igV2G32toiUlJYLc9FN 
ISCjmGqltOHFwQKQ3QXm4Lp7EbzraNdO79bOG6Id1EHZBuYvqSbvDTEKSbrBvSrQdqqxs2SQ 
oOvBps4oyhJmxySMxDhleg1ulfqXeDITF556c/L+0dzyZeYRojpJEFNQ+qhl7QLWvVCvCt9a 
ENEWsTHvSm9Mw+P9O1KbAxHpspuAVyOJTRL+NsiErHaMWPc8eONEIxiRvHUvMm6K/zj32ZLw 
QMhYDBtwwz++k5qJ6Qj2O8YWJjX7kS0VVKy+YzWvoA5nBUwUMQrlMjBGGBI7HhkABh08wKAM 
OLPTo/G5v29Lk0oKOVvGwNKdE3B9FELprxxXxjwDbGrLfEVZyrt0MhFFpFXQEsxtlLHvhKrd 
UZHdpJa0bBdPQZK7RDsC/HfNXIzrNjuzKdAdL6M4ppqn6EGKm+phvjD3vXs/LHTdraK3+aQl 
zKv3Kr3nQ/PnR/3U/Y0jxUT9M1ZcPikxXjsRUCxx6nrAH5YPWO8JaCh7D0dJM5FpESnQw32q 
0iVoVa8JkbSETzqRZYg8IMhXax8TvVa6q9w6BMINaCWnCWrQOGw3C+GVDTXSbZXVoYsBZ46H 
V5euJZs4lNvCDh+sU6eOYiOHY1l2qhg42Ymtq3NObpBlbXnjGipsd2MXqsmlXtjfIFviyLuz 
1h6GT6SCqeuC+vaJliacYfePbCYRUprxmDRi5rQFoYck033EtwIL/GEQF2A1PAoFMuMeua5t 
vtvyXCFxctufvo1IYvoKYGXkHfBAKHERqV8onhaS8XsWCZPHHrR5L+4UejIul3LupzMpWw/m 
M++lU+83hFuXc7qWUFR7zSHtVOjAKXRuXaSehS69f7ELeNuI3iZLKNEaj1nGMM3GgXIPGWvd 
d9OamGlauLd9SOzfxSGZlxpOVH3yFlRq2SVaU4LYwxR4oP+COljTsxGLheYQsCGMjOtRifNd 
t4RvGdayNY/HBREpWQZsWyA1MCpw+mobeBbDCe26LCM+nPsvBsSQezDf+RIGZAIAWPlHDltf 
Jrzu7/ndUlDvvC2R+j0ji5740Y/FGu0XT4p81w47nDD6wgHvzZg5+PrSnduKN7cXIN/qDlp9 
8ahxs9L/5g95oQCX0iBACCCGVQFkrSbLMxphqWasf4QwhNRJr9A6+dMQCAxN5iocqAcIRlN+ 
eRdWaTKgTdtdwWfX9JBmMmAm3TyC9s0otAJYxbuLZFwKpk0m8mWLmqKFCVVTKZLYqh4O35CJ 
2wc/mNluGjMIdNR//k8ejnspH/KT1ztIU43+MFZLcOY7KgiP8wnR8Alqk5vwAiPW8WhoeHMb 
HWtTZIdpPmKTzYqI8VfXOkg0Hnob6FRB3ovmiq2bwNAlydRGU8X7qvnC9NUJ5eobwKbeWBti 
r3FGO8mFVzZsG+B7bciDbuvg1DNA0gLowC40GoWyTB8OJ6WgDuQzzCIYIhEcLBNZgtlcH4LE 
XR7hq+FBWFadNo84OPaAopdDkMIlrokdTGWkmX26ngGwvhFc5lQtqJ82OoCeHbhuBD2/ieBH 
58c+C2InHo/CTW3KDQUDErPzNSsyGfa1rE4Me3m7BiayjLQ50oqrlRFbH2tdd6UHj1t65ESj 
PeSqG6bEq2BQ9SB7IjeridTvQcDekp09By45Y0tcwGDRVXd4u/7qaS6TOzLr3OmlMg5Y1KPn 
CLGq1lBh2LKRxeWPrCx2gJiREvu0rUWKB1Jx5rld+nFyShySwSy7pwT3MgOqrHxbLbAitmrp 
c1C9c9VWDCPeJMWMEuQYNh/bUbjz6L/LTvvXzBG8hfm+W8Xn8720MhnSQT4GbIskJ4rWwFRY 
o9BXCivEviqZ9NL+xtnhvIuXh29iR1x/S5E0rdEgiw36zsCAlLSaZ29AxQ0KOZl34RxvOPzI 
Crm92hHAsUXlHHKdhJaqEM3hpSxtmLFfCUdcBDBcO4eGtGBzH0qoa2TzG1fWqI/UyhsUpROt 
wIuWLy+uuX/M+aKp8IEgwnLawi42T9zL2/BODezl38ZvScHJxfIaAsEJT1uz9Yivun117iiA 
WdnyBhQTAdRKKTgVD5eypFYu0UTWJG0YRSNPP+e9mbU6to3BsTWJYw1B9U8xll1A+PAscjId 
QFbugRUCe08cu9/4Rf7nPtYOHyVQgCQ43Sa9PhNvPIeGSiSqMHw9MwNmbrbCV7pW0HR+iXNz 
PSpfwspOXxrkXzu6YMZN6sy2CQbXEkvrVVACuoKwWDe4IbyL7JPI+cQHUGbPgogOGaj2qKUQ 
ioR8/tKY4rJtd6rB/4USOBxyAWQxRXJAtdOwixI5ISQwyynL5y7J3PvQuazby1e1YnpMRsTZ 
23tbNKB1PJZ2fwaYAAXqPjRY7dwcPjEUAdnOUkp0OCPZH+1R29DO4uV+zDVV3ILSU4N4r6G9 
KgcPFopODKiSsKQfg11H56Ap9lfu96ZxHi95O3PNiA+P2+uy9a2IkntD2RKiABcO6P/uGmTp 
F0VDFZT5u3OcVMl+xBy7x1Yz98bP3hnqf7AY5dveaGzjqPrVcOHeA8MtY+QjWTUUf9VltEV2 
ED99rTJD9kaONDur/mZMXLfLJjaChx70duw3SQ3g0wCihLMtRpoeXZlQ4UzrEJ/MPfWzEAhP 
3g00dugPLHNxkfhfIPT/wClbefemsXlK3D9ynSmp16uiDwaeSntTECiUH6gd5f62xbEtQDoY 
KYwdK+3YY+GH81wg23fVtT/FVFv85EeOvGeJTf61BfR0MGkx/f5wmqQvM0IdCSMUnMGjanYk 
axX9jaHqbVWNgTFSnwmt8znkUd84IE+dWV5E/6aFzfQ2SmFy+EHQyJa6lByc+RH0NzgTKzNN 
ZQnaUxAo/Go9c9jLwOY8/G67YQgYRNx9+6GW7sv/nCbajG8eH1I51VXkWLzhVHShGWvCYsLL 
E88QVoOjOqqfYoBZVrlYSjRXY2JSOAIOTiCgT/CYXmDt8InHGH6gxzKRc+bxyqb29LsDam49 
NLLECG/dLD4ZMNw0Dd74zekIay41V1L5QXv9GqR+92z1jCM5awt/aXEu5l4X37S88hKu7KDu 
k1iwKD8DJUJLuqJnN5JKTImg/8UuwNp/Q5H1WQtS66syj5Vg5bYDiElI14IZQNiGwm/anxD+ 
4Bev1Z4d+LYaSusIVgKqbhu7dGQNtPSVyIJ/jOsWQQmBokcp4OIQDotCAJHEWxMSl46Vb+KN 
fwVL/+zdZ9yPaY/JeDVVrjqiErcK0rySsC95hZJILJUIag56BT/+wk950dwbwqglfSgIYGc+ 
70pES/lHog61Z3cRJdcziP4xxKn44sxlJLDr52C7DS8lnfvy16853XBI8+llnXq2AcHNixJr 
h/90CTU4fd36Z1tKrMnFBYahbeofHKrDs+HuC3pFaU/hja3Ls51hXr22dmWmMfyeUN3SxJqp 
hqjrbGdmuqEVO13IhSVHOtKKgwpE4KC5HL73oSCZEv7vtuta1RFLhGAQ3T3jrM8y1SgQ8Kuy 
MmzDNNLLqBqi2sLffwVPT7vsEq12/Tx0pMKrD8NZzw4WqflialIelxDXC5ZQ5z9K6iB4RdnS 
/jyliVzv8XPrjjcaDa+Ie+9C0on1i76ydQHl978CdTYmVWm8SFu5dz+IVNBBly8RDc1bUo4U 
cXzffhrUmm/RfW5Jtv0/v2xy77T6Brs/v9p6Ccf/3oq1A+/OyrZ6A8cvzrb0G56fmet6Hcum 
v5u1A+9eKnUPmD08Y5XaXyb1++vgnKzxx66ENQfu3QM6jcetvNMSgbbv/1YihfmvftpVCuv+ 
eXcSj/7f5LuqH8xuI3USnKLBGfqB0UE4ZHCYl8o8h2xtiM4bacIreBePgJrnzffuceKLvb93 
5MnpFlVK9xeIuHeICJJqM+LOAYiUW8CsFtujfhAzW+Nj6ExGd5LeLGj41fBjdW3L5kCfHgur 
sWL4Mbty7Y0Ew8+Og957fAjRP33NVCPPj54mXXoBtf/BtUGsfixwa6puTQZYSvAt86B3qgpj 
W+lX+Ofgethq71sGnklkPgKePQyzCGLh4QE/1a5+yg5peF64RyDaIbYKVl37H5RqLjbonicZ 
y1zeTJtjXIUBpUlQx+Zl1UJ11b5J2cGvK2z7ieIe8Z8qbIW9Q7gAahPD1+N1JLV2k/nAvl82 
f7FkKZ/PXExVD+1eEvXw7lNw8/hcrtd15zJZRfufOTqEzee6IVyuxfP3E1lEevfHE9lEPN4/ 
1dU+FNQ/5Zj54pZnP9umEzjPwqGZ/Ss2UM+QV0ngWYQtL73UOhA/3PND+P8L8kfuUAj9eFHl 
+IOjNVI2+opuKEk+c4dTcY2piPvAzp9ETsMMn6dlJR/hnTmKDf6Oiibn0hCmSywQuAvZSCCu 
1t0QsatEdSbWEeVoV8NICo1rp6tGuz4rqMNp6Do0NdKCBecBYsSyKx4DUr5dGgP9S0+/XzK6 
8P5MbUSXUs3RDQW6M1L8FdeQOO3l9gv+/dF2qGlPEueYR+Adf1TRSVTOXhlkyxUHmInR4AYx 
lE0k7JaO+W/mmA4UpVdPCi1TGg4sNI7OolMTlp7lKQICZumQkNKNCakXJXqOHCIndli6xFGk 
d1KxdXvrWG7nl207vKc6wNBKwYzspDDxw1YyScCKsMokzlMCt9Y5oJZ7iisfSXTB5VyAMnFG 
J/fAApwtlfbbiedI1rbKEIPg27S6cmOob49E5dqaPKlS92WX/aBa1jrLQP88hkkDUb1hr84/ 
te7kRW/GUf6OKxBmc7KLC3iyAUoDPizQMZlW0pOfI2lONLNlUWQz5thctNcDwv8KS3b9+2Oa 
uOK+I+JEVxrJcF2EXiaYqUxJhDSuRXIrugBPyW3doO4r4PI/GByJovevFRCP+1wEtlilkYcb 
HhB4BDduv7U3l1VFOAG8ENKUmJigJzvfF+5w10LD/2AtQYMoru+mAcbSpmR1Rjo2LsrVQrEG 
JCKExNGGbGd+6LdU2pepxx4O0Plz3/l2g59omTR/6XJ8lmahx48S05EgJyeujtypXxYXnuaA 
UbZYNOiLlqgQ0/iALGEkgr7+FIiHWNNB4isNsg0jiZALPWAeX5Co7fLsqDK+tT6IGMOp3k7E 
wMbhrE4MoE5RGDQ4Exq0mLh2sefRIJCpbHOahKBwgD8VBqfw4/Huoodhg013yoxUmgGqgttV 
/3qPUmtPdQOPaVkz9Ebs0VOxv/r9qnZ7D1W1Yf4z2CHh5EtTM0lFsrcih9tdxa0XQTf4uq0i 
ahy6FzJYq+MEMrsMO55XqO447ir6zNILZFAkVLN3rR5EKu99R6bTRBrbnBsI9VxjoUzw93/r 
/20NObIOLz+qqjg1A++E8XjEDZ9f3PjobJ1w4HqFz4Bjcup+iAbGwunNnBiJhvuzblFdQNLG 
E2Goo99XVTPXwJDLHOQSaVEbNSrXEHl2J7PPGag/XL7bicJIkDrgk8GH/wzUUpItX3TF8Kce 
cfbXhhtNZxWpLwzkF/ZLVwm6Dl9aCMxjEDmZJDg5jENPuoCrodzM6QOVKBR7uYmAhx3O5koi 
+ksnDI78lHjY8A2X3qsfVba6McJCwB/8XxMibCpoLBH6mS348FJghJnwzD+rPwLoy/79y1tW 
Y5/DRr92RUxbDBA7mf1kru2rpcYb/9zVjmwWQCHTKG49U9i30ABHUybwxjBlShOFIwiY18a/ 
2HTw5B9swHGaeAHAmsmPZN5od0OEqECxWNNirqYnuzyLk5FeEXwfZmrnfraJMzl04BsuzPKK 
ap8n3MyVvgNlGcgziF20s02zwcIB/MeLpPAcaut4Fs58XjZh9+XFHMxh7PGDgoovx1sJBbgf 
2/LhatkKGpjnGwjNuS4f98RAUlcPU6sDKsOzp59tiXQO190nj276C8f/Lxr0LZf6j34RptKC 
DBhQ/7QWZFSsvmM1r6QE3MXdGDsaUVpkx/HAI5+i/ZcsvHqL6wEndb8GLphY7IqoKtQx355T 
3SZkcqup7S/F7tECZ9GrmjNNz+OBFECb1RCtpYulRsorptWhV61x5XN0HnYb+A8/+Hf/4I2m 
LV2PQY8rnm3fBtKLv/9D++C2X8z+/9ZyhP3Z8/XhNfjN9T4zmN018rkvEaN0lwHnrl8Y0Z0U 
hSDKMJiWAQz0eo3R0ScaRqQdxOQRn15HFA7gwi5DT7HvxWZ1NOH4PbHtC5M/2MIcCvRCfjFG 
t3o6FCEwQFGAONv4skknF8/ieeRH98eeHqY0Sccv6l6WfQKsIX/vW4UBSDDTHnaZwoMt6jZ/ 
Ol+tYLrDRSlFyrm+qIru/doJpc71xU+qNvn5IpogVt523MkAgfa3vxytQLgLpdzf94Csl38v 
X5lZ51w4rG6qP4hidUC1aBb9JyY/r+lHbQnd8CfyQSbausP5Ltq10vn1d+eaNijGs5V3TalU 
gDA1pXNPVsCRWj2uk5+BqyR4VLG6hF5oWI2fWc2Zcb21oiYVjSuAqG1tbaFkvrRmyjNgrGXN 
qMWcMqxJZf1dEyopnNseW96qgKidGxjngs2ZboaPZI2UHbF3phTz7KBCrYGeFppZgxW3Mjvw 
GfvqWM";
```